# RabbitMQ cluster on IoT devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-cluster

I am designing IoT system with board computers such as raspberry pi.
Particularly, am designing application messaging platform that enables pub-sub, esb and so on.

To make it easy and simple, I am considering to employ rabbitmq.
Furthermore, I want to build rabbitmq cluster on those node, to avoid SPoF.

However, those devices sometimes will be turned off.
I think this means a node leaves from cluster temporarily.
I expect rabbitmq cluster assumes this situation a certain degree, but I cannot assume how much it is able to accept, what problems occurs.

To experts of rabbitmq cluster,
Could you tell me any concerns about it, and cases that we should care, please?
Do you think it does work in production?
Please tell me any cases similar to my assumption.

I really look forward to your reply.
Even if it is tiny things, would be nice for me.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR RabbitMQ doesn't work well in this scenario. Better use another thing.

RabbitMQ is intended to work with stable nodes, it uses the Raft algorithm for distributed consensus and elects their leader (see http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft). As we can observe with this approach the process to elect a leader is compounded by several steps. If the network is partitioned or the leader fails another leader must be elected. If this happens frequently the entire network would be unstable.

Maybe you could want to have a look at other technologies like https://deepstream.io.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understood that the rabbitmq doesn't fit to IoT scenario. I would like to consider another plan.

Comment: RabbitMQ supports the MQTT protocol but again, it needs to have stable nodes thus one node per device will not work. Here https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/21/uniting-amqp-and-mqtt-message-brokering-with-rabbitmq/ we have an use case with RabbitMQ + MQTT + Raspberry, maybe you want to have a look at that.